# A Simple Mental Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

I kinda wasted a lot of time on this. Hope you enjoy it:

```
7  | 9 | 58 

9  | 3 | ? 

11 | 4 | 125
```

The '?' will be:

- 82
- 83
- 84
- 87

Comment: i don't think you're meant to put the answer in the question ^^

Comment: @L_Church I'm not sure if it's really wrong to do it, the puzzle might also be to find a logical explanation as to why is this the answer.

Comment: " '?' will be: (options)" Is saying: What will the missing value be? The answer matched up too lol. Just for reference, answers are left for us to find lol

Comment: Sorry kinda late to reply but if you think its against policy of SE to give options then anyone can edit the answer as you may know , Anyway people it was just for fun and also its motive is reached please dont overthink on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $7^2+9=49+9=58$
> $11^2+4=121+4=125$
> That clears the logic that is Square of first number added to second number results in third number. So,
> $9^2+3=81+3=84$